# need help on generating a non repeating array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, random

Have a interview quiz lately, and I really struggling here. There are few steps of question, but this final one is making me cracking my brain.

I created 4 set of function mainly is to randomize: 
1. alphabet (object_one)
2. integer (object_two)
3. real number (object_three)
4. alphanumerical (object_four)

The final one is to create an random array based on my 4 set of object.
Eg: hisadfnnasd, 126263, assfdgsga12348fas, 13123.123,
lizierdjfklaasf, 123192u3kjwekhf, 89181811238,122, 
nmarcysfa900jkifh  , 3.781, 2.11, ....

But this is my code for the final one:

```
function final_one(min,max,dec){
var obj = [object_one(min,max),object_two(min,max),object_three(min,max,dec),object_four(min,max)]; 
var output = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    output += obj[random(0,3)] + ", ";
}
return output;
```

}

my output will be something like this:

```
jkwnh1365624sp, 275995, jkwnh1365624sp, 43, jkwnh1365624sp, 275995, 275995, 43, 275995, 275995,
```

Data are keep repeating.

Please help!

Comment: You should tag the programming language you're using (looks like javascript)

Comment: Data keeps repeating because your `obj` has only 4 elements. So when you do `obj[random(0,3)]`, it will basically pick a random element out of 4 elements and return it. Because there's only 4 elements, it will looks repeated (e.g. some element will appears 3+ time). What do you want to achieve in your `final_one` function? A random string based on the 4 provided strings?

Comment: you've 4 elements in array and looking for 10 unique elements...howz this possible??

Comment: @DatNguyen yep, a random string with no repeating data, eg: hisadfnnasd, 126263, assfdgsga12348fas, 13123.123,
lizierdjfklaasf, 123192u3kjwekhf, 89181811238,122, nmarcysfa900jkifh , 3.781, 2.11, ....

Comment: @ELITE yea thats my mistake there, but just that i cant figure how to solve it..

Comment: Are there any constraints, e.g. must use only characters/digits from the 4 given strings, must have both numbers and strings, number must be valid (e.g. no `2.11.11`). With the current context, there're literally thousands of ways to generate a 10 random strings from 4 strings (in fact, we can always generate 10 random strings without any given strings).

Comment: what is `object_one(min,max), object_two(min,max)`??

Comment: @DatNguyen there are only 1 decimal for the real number, for object 1(alphabet) will have only alphabet, no uppercase. For object 2 (integer), will be sets of random numbers. For object 3 (real number), which one decimal place, but the number can go up to `3000.456`. For object 4(alphanumeric) will be alphabet and number mix up, the space in front and back will not exceed 10 spaces `nmarcysfa900jkifh`, `assfdgsga12348fas`, just that I need to generate these 4 objects with no repeating output for it..

Answer (score 0):

when you create obj, you execute all 4 functions once:

```
var obj = [object_one(min,max),object_two(min,max),object_three(min,max,dec),object_four(min,max)];
```

object_one(min,max) is a function call.

This creates an array of 4 elements, somthing like this: ['v', 5, 3.14, 'x']
As @Dat pointed out, random(0,3) picks one of these elements.

What you are trying to do is to have an array of functions:

```
var obj = [object_one, object_two, object_three, object_four];
```

and have one of the functions randomly executed (like this):

```
obj[random(0,3)](min, max, dec);
```

some of the functions have no dec parameter but that is ok in javascript.

I hope I understood your requirements correctly.

Comment: thanks for helping, but still wandering how do i expand my data with this 4 functions and without having them repeat?

Comment: With this you get a randomly picked object type and a randomly picked object. What else you need fir the "expansion" to happen?